# How do we convert scientific notation to number in Javascript

Tags: javascript, numbers

So if I do `712569312664357328695151392 + 8100824045303269669937` 
I want the result to be:

```
712577413488402631964821329
```

But instead I have

> 7.125774134884027e+26

Comment: Please have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742578/bigdecimal-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid scientific notation for large numbers in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685680/how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-for-large-numbers-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

```
let a = 712569312664357328695151392;
let b = 8100824045303269669937;
```

`(BigInt(a) + BigInt(b)).toString()` will give you your expected result.

Comment: You Sir, have my respect and my thanks. This answer should be put on the home page of SO