# How can I simplify this code to get a correct decimal place for a number?

Tags: javascript

Here's the code below:

```
let moneyToReturn = 0.5
let note = 0.01
let sum = 0

while(moneyToReturn-note>=0){ 

    moneyToReturn = ((moneyToReturn*10 - note*10)/10).toFixed(2)
    sum = ((sum*10 + note*10)/10).toFixed(2)

//  moneyToReturn -= note
//  sum += note

    console.log(sum)
}
```

To make sure that I'm not logging my **sum** with crazy decimal places on each computation I need to write this code.

```
((x * 10 + y * 10)/10).toFixed(2)
```

What is the better/shorter way of doing that?

Comment: You could define a function that accepts an integer (cents) which then divides the parameter by 100 and returns the .toFixed(2) value so it's more reusable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could use `parseFloat` to avoid then need for your arithmetic like so?

```
while(moneyToReturn-note>=0){ 

    moneyToReturn = parseFloat((moneyToReturn - note).toFixed(2))
    sum = parseFloat((sum + note).toFixed(2))

//  moneyToReturn -= note
//  sum += note

    console.log(sum)
}
```

You should find that the use of `parseFloat` as shown above is functionally equivalent to `((x * 10 + y * 10)/10).toFixed(2)` as the following code sample shows:

```js
var x = 0.1
var y = 0.3

console.log('Current method', ((x * 10 + y * 10)/10).toFixed(2) )
console.log('Concise method', (parseFloat(x + y).toFixed(2)) )
```

Comment: Thanks. Your solutions look a little better.  Now I'm pondering that dealing with numbers in javascript is quite complicated and you really need to be careful especially if high precision is needed.

Comment: Beware. When I worked as a programmer in the financial industry, we _never_ used floating point arithmetic because of the accrued rounding errors.  You'd base money on fixed fractions of a cent, say 1-100th of a cent, and use _decimal_ math (like Java's BigDecimal class) — see this SO question: [BigDecimal in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16742578/17300)