# How to divide by huge number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, bigint

I am trying to do this:

```js
const numerator = 268435456;
const denominator = 2 ** 64;
const decimalFraction = numerator / denominator;
```

To make this work, I have tried to use the code suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54409977/3846032:

```js
const rawValue = 268435456n;
const exponent = 2n ** 64n;
const precision = 100_000_000;
const fraction = Number((rawValue * BigInt(precision)) / exponent) / precision;
```

When I run this in dev it works fine, but in prod I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: can't convert BigInt to number
```

I believe it is coming from `2n ** 64n`.

I'm using create-react-app and some digging reveals this: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6907#issuecomment-778178677).

Unfortunately this suggestion makes it fail in both dev and prod with an OOM error.

Any suggestions on how to make this work would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you still using normal numbers with BigInt? `precision` should use BigInt as well: `100_000_000n`, so then you'd just use `(rawValue * precision) / exponent / precision`.

Comment: Because I want to get a decimal `number` at the end of this. Regardless, if I try what you suggest, unfortunately I still get the same problem with the OOM.

Comment: `268435456 / Math.pow(2, 64)` gives me the expected `1.4551915228366852e-11` in my react-app

Comment: Ahhh, the OOM was a problem later in the code, my bad. Let me write an answer summarizing what to do.

Comment: You'll need more than `100_000_000` for the precision because the quotient of your example is on the order of 1e-11.  In other words, even if your example worked, it would display 0.  e.g.: `Number((268435456n * 100_000_000n) / 2n ** 64n) / 100_000_000` is `0`. but `Number((268435456n * 100_000_000_000n) / 2n ** 64n) / 100_000_000_000` is `1e-11`

Answer (score 0):

Use `Math.pow(2, 64)` instead of `2 ** 64`:

```js
const Example = () => {

    const x = 268435456;
    const y = Math.pow(2, 64);

    return (x / y);
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the OOM I was getting was unrelated to this particular problem, so disregard that part.

As for this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: can't convert BigInt to number
```

You can avoid it by doing `Math.power(2, 64)` instead of `2n ** 64n`.

The issue in question: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11705.

Comment: You probably mean `2n ** 64n` and not `2 ** 64`. `2 ** 64` should be equivalent to `Math.pow(2, 64)`.

Comment: Yes true, my mistake, updated!