# Rounding up or down when 0.5

Tags: javascript, math, rounding, precision

I am having an issue with the way Javascript is rounding numbers when hitting 0.5.
I am writing levies calculators, and am noticing a 0.1c discrepancy in the results.

The problem is that the result for them is `21480.705` which my application translates into `21480.71`, whereas the tariff says `21480.70`.

This is what I am seeing with Javascript:

```
(21480.105).toFixed(2)
"21480.10"
(21480.205).toFixed(2)
"21480.21"
(21480.305).toFixed(2)
"21480.31"
(21480.405).toFixed(2)
"21480.40"
(21480.505).toFixed(2)
"21480.51"
(21480.605).toFixed(2)
"21480.60"
(21480.705).toFixed(2)
"21480.71"
(21480.805).toFixed(2)
"21480.81"
(21480.905).toFixed(2)
"21480.90"
```

Questions:

- What the hell is going on with this erratic rouding?
- What's the quickest easiest way to get a "rounded up" result (when hitting 0.5)?

Comment: [Answer to question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @robby `console.log(21480.105)` gets logged correctly though.

Comment: @kaiido my point is that the number itself is accurate, this is a flaw in the rounding algorithm toFixed is using (or am I wrong completely)?

Comment: @JonasWilms wrong completely. You're letting yourself be deceived by JavaScript's policy on how to convert floating-point values to string. It will try to display something shorter than the actual number stored in the variable. The actual number is not exactly 21480.105, yet that is what is displayed. That should be your clue that your reasoning was missing something.

Comment: Never ever use floating point for calculations where you need an exact result, e.g., when working with money.

Comment: `(21480.105).toPrecision(18)` tells `"21480.1049999999996"`, a little bit smaller than expected. And `toFixed(2)` of this number is `21480.10`.

Comment: @kumesana but usually `.toString` does show the additional digits (`0.1 + 0.2 + ""`) funny that it doesn't in this case.

Comment: @JonasWilms The policy is complex. Just like the real value taken out of a written litteral, will be the closest value to the written literal that can be represented in floating-point ; when converting to string automatically the string will be the shortest written number, of which the real value is the closest. In the examples you give, if the string conversion did not write these digits, then a value that can be represented in floating-point, will exist and be closer to the written value, than the actual value of the variable.

Answer (score 3):

So as some of the others already explained the reason for the 'erratic' rounding is a floating point precision problem. You can investigate this by using the `toExponential()` method of a JavaScript number.

```
(21480.905).toExponential(20)
#>"2.14809049999999988358e+4"
(21480.805).toExponential(20)
#>"2.14808050000000002910e+4"
```

As you can see here `21480.905`, gets a double representation that is slightly smaller than `21480.905`, while `21480.805` gets a double representation slightly larger than the original value. Since the `toFixed()` method works with the double representation and has no idea of your original intended value, it does all it can and should do with the information it has.

One way to work around this, is to shift the decimal point to the number of decimals you require by multiplication, then use the standard `Math.round()`, then shift the decimal point back again, either by division or multiplication by the inverse. Then finally we call  `toFixed()` method to make sure the output value gets correctly zero-padded.

```js
var x1 = 21480.905;
var x2 = -21480.705;

function round_up(x,nd)
{
  var rup=Math.pow(10,nd);
  var rdwn=Math.pow(10,-nd); // Or you can just use 1/rup
  return (Math.round(x*rup)*rdwn).toFixed(nd)
}
function round_down(x,nd)
{
  var rup=Math.pow(10,nd);
  var rdwn=Math.pow(10,-nd); 
  return (Math.round(x*-rup)*-rdwn).toFixed(nd)
}

function round_tozero(x,nd)
{
   return x>0?round_down(x,nd):round_up(x,nd) 
}



console.log(x1,'up',round_up(x1,2));
console.log(x1,'down',round_down(x1,2));
console.log(x1,'to0',round_tozero(x1,2));

console.log(x2,'up',round_up(x2,2));
console.log(x2,'down',round_down(x2,2));
console.log(x2,'to0',round_tozero(x2,2));
```

Finally:
Encountering a problem like this is usually a good time to sit down and have a long think about wether you are actually using the correct data type for your problem. Since floating point errors can accumulate with iterative calculation, and since people are sometimes strangely sensitive with regards to money magically disappearing/appearing in the CPU, maybe you would be better off keeping monetary counters in integer 'cents' (or some other well thought out structure) rather than floating point 'dollar'.

Comment: I need to round `21480.705` to `21480.70`, rather than `21480.71` (because this is what the port calculator seems to be doing). Arghhhhh

Comment: Using negative rup, rdwn will round down for 0.5 case  instead of up, but note that it will also round downward for negative numbers (not towards zero)  . If you always want to round 0.5 cases towards zero you can  add an if case for negative numbers

Comment: Could you turn this into a function? If you do, I think this should be the accepted answer, as it's the most flexible one and least hacky one too

Comment: @Merc, I've edited the answer to it turn into functions. The function names are somewhat deceptive, but they describe how the 0.5 case is handled, not the general case rounding functionality.

Answer (score 1):

This works in most cases. (See note below.)

> The rounding problem can be avoided by using numbers represented in
>   exponential notation:

```js
function round(value, decimals) {
  return Number(Math.round(value+'e'+decimals)+'e-'+decimals);
}

console.log(round(21480.105, 2).toFixed(2));
```

Found at http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/rounding-in-javascript/

**NOTE:** As pointed out by Mark Dickinson, this is not a general solution because it returns NaN in certain cases, such as `round(0.0000001, 2)` and with large inputs.
Edits to make this more robust are welcome.

Comment: I need to round `21480.705` to `21480.70`, rather than `21480.71` (because this is what the port calculator seems to be doing). Arghhhhh

Comment: What happens when you try this solution with `value = 0.000001`?

Comment: @MarkDickinson I get `0.00` in the snippet. Did you get a different result? -- Or if the concern is about precision, you'd get more invoking `round` (and `toFixed`) with different arguments (`round(0.123456, 5).toFixed(5)`

Comment: @Merc To come up with a "correct" script that matches your port calculator's output, you'd need to know what rules it's following. It's easy to add an exception along the lines of `if(val%1==0.705){ return roundDownForNoGoodReason(val); }`, (although this exact logic wouldn't work for the same reason as your original code, but you get the idea) -- but unless you can foresee all such exceptions, there are going to be mismatches between the two algorithms.

Comment: @Cat: sorry, I missed out a zero. Try `0.0000001 + 'e' + 2` and you'll get `"1e-7e2"`, which isn't going to round well: I get `NaN` as a result of `Math.round(0.0000001 + 'e' + 2)`. Same issue with large inputs. So this isn't a general solution: it's got some limitations, which are probably worth documenting.

Answer (score 1):

The why -

You may have heard that in some languages, such as JavaScript, numbers with a fractional part are calling floating-point numbers, and floating-point numbers are about dealing with approximations of numeric operations. Not exact calculations, approximations. Because how exactly would you expect to compute and store 1/3 or square root of 2, with exact calculations?

If you had not, then now you've heard of it.

That means that when you type in the number literal 21480.105, the actual value that ends up stored in computer memory is not actually 21480.105, but an *approximation* of it. The value closest to 21480.105 that can be represented as a floating-point number.

And since this value is not *exactly* 21480.105, that means it is either slightly *more* than that, or slightly *less* than that. More will be rounded up, and less will be rounded down, as expected.

The solution -

Your problem comes from approximations, that it seems you cannot afford. The solution is to work with exact numbers, not approximate.

Use whole numbers. Those are exact. Add in a fractional dot when you convert your numbers to string.

Answer (score 0):

You could round to an Integer, then shift in a comma while displaying:

```
function round(n, digits = 2) {
  // rounding to an integer is accurate in more cases, shift left by "digits" to get the number of digits behind the comma
  const str = "" + Math.round(n * 10 ** digits);

  return str
    .padStart(digits + 1, "0") // ensure there are enough digits, 0 -> 000 -> 0.00
    .slice(0, -digits) + "." + str.slice(-digits); // add a comma at "digits" counted from the end
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> What the hell is going on with this erratic rouding?

Please reference the cautionary [Mozilla Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed), which identifies the cause for these discrepancies. "Floating point numbers cannot represent all decimals precisely in binary which can lead to unexpected results..."

Also, please reference [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) (Thank you Robby Cornelissen for the reference)

> What's the quickest easiest way to get a "rounded up" result (when hitting 0.5)?

Use a JS library like [accounting.js](https://openexchangerates.github.io/accounting.js/) to round, format, and present currency.

For example...

```js
function roundToNearestCent(rawValue) {
  return accounting.toFixed(rawValue, 2);
}

const roundedValue = roundToNearestCent(21480.105);
console.log(roundedValue);
```

```html
<script src="https://combinatronics.com/openexchangerates/accounting.js/master/accounting.js"></script>
```

Also, consider checking out [BigDecimal in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742578/bigdecimal-in-javascript).

Hope that helps!

Comment: `(Math.round(21480.105*100)/100).toPrecision(18)` produces `"21480.1100000000006"` because of rounding. This does not mean, that this works for all calculations of this type.

Comment: toPrecision() is causing the loss of accuracy, not the method proposed in this answer. Please see the first 2 links provided in the answer to better understand why floating point may not properly store all decimal values.

Comment: And `Math.round(1.005*100)/100` produces `1`. And if displaying 2 fraction digits using `(Math.round(1.005*100)/100).toFixed(2)` it shows `1.00` again, because 1.005*100 is 100.4999  and rounded down. So it doesn't help!

Comment: Point well taken. I've amended my answer to account for this.

Comment: Then think about this: floats are stored based on power of 2. So decimal fractions that are not n/p with p multiple of 2 are always not exact, but rounded. Each mathematical operation (add, mult, div,..) makes the result more unexact.