# Emulate input type="number" with numbers bigger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` (9007199254740992)?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to emulate `<input type="text">` to behave like `<input type="number">` (up/down arrow keys increase/decrease value)

So far it works fine, except when value reaches `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` (9007199254740992) it stops increasing, but `type="number"` can go beyond that number.
Is there a way I can somehow bypass this limitation in javascript?

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]'),
      step = {ArrowUp: 1, ArrowDown: -1};

input.addEventListener("keydown", (e) =>
{
  if (step[e.key])
  {
    input.value = Number(input.value) + step[e.key];
    return e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>type="text"</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="9007199254740990"></td>
    <td>use UP/DOWN arrow keys</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>type="number"</td>
    <td><input type="number" value="9007199254740990"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As per @CertainPerformance answer `BigInt()` seems to be a good work around, however it doesn't allow use float numbers.
Also, with float numbers if `step` is set to for example 1.4, it shows some weird numbers like `4.199999999999999`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply using BigInt notation instead looks to do the trick:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]'),
      step = {ArrowUp: 1n, ArrowDown: -1n};

input.addEventListener("keydown", (e) =>
{
  if (step[e.key])
  {
    input.value = BigInt(input.value) + step[e.key];
    return e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>type="text"</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="9007199254740990"></td>
    <td>use UP/DOWN arrow keys</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>type="number"</td>
    <td><input type="number" value="9007199254740990"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you're concerned about obsolete browsers, you can use an [alternative implementation](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/jsbi/blob/master/README.md) replicating BigInt.

Comment: Thank you! It even better than the native type="number" input...
For whatever reason when I've tried it before it was giving me error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot mix BigInt and other types, use explicit conversions`. Weirdly your example works fine...

Comment: You might've missed to change the `ArrowUp: 1` to `ArrowUp: 1n` etc - that'll allow the `+ step[e.key]` to work.

Comment: Yes, yes, I was using regular numbers for that.

Comment: Hmmm this method however doesn't support float numbers...

Comment: Yeah, it's BigInt, not BigDecimal. If you want large decimals, consider: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742578/bigdecimal-in-javascript