# How to stop Javascript from rounding numbers after 16 decimal places?

Tags: javascript, math, infinity

Let's say I have the following code:

`console.log(1 / 3);`

It prints "0.3333333333333333".

Is there a way to not have it stop?

(For any curious souls: it's for calcuating Pi)

Comment: No, you'll need to implement the calculation with the desired precision yourself, perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/q/16742578

Comment: Do you want to print 16 decimenls after 0? Or do you want to get something like 0.3  ?

Comment: `calculating Pi` - you do know that the digits of Pi is infinite right? It's also infinitely non-repeating (unilke 0.33333... which repeats after 1 digit)

Comment: @debugger no, I want it to go on forever.

Comment: @slebetman Yes I understand that. Don't question it, and just let me know if there is a way.

Comment: `console.log((1/3).toFixed(50))` did you mean this?

Comment: Would something that simply did `process.stdout.write('3')` in a loop meet your needs? If not, why not? Meta: the question seems ill-posed - there are probably thousands of ways to alter what you're doing to "not have it stop", but I suspect that there are additional constraints that you're not telling us about.

Comment: Not have it stop? Not ever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a function whrere the numbers are multiplied with precision before they
divided:

```js
function div(num1, num2, prec=100) {
  return (num1*prec)/(num2*prec).toFixed(prec)
}

console.log(div(1,3,100));
console.log(div(11,13,100));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.toFixed` method:

```js
console.log((1/3).toFixed(2))
```

Comment: This has some unintended side-effects. If you do:
`console.log((1 / 3).toFixed(100));`
it returns 0.3333333333333333148296162562473909929394721984863281250000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Plus it only goes up to 100.