# Parse Float string to number rounding off javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bignum, parsefloat

I have the string "9999999999999.99999" which I covert using Parse Float. But it changes the value to 10000000000000 , is there anyway I can have the get the number same without rounding off?

The input is string and out must be number not string.
ex: ParseFloat("9999999999999.99999") = 9999999999999.99999 .
So the output should not be string instead number

Comment: Counter question - do you *need* this as a number? If you're not doing any mathematical operations, it shouldn't matter what the type of the data is.

Comment: Yes it has to number as its an input field which user types. so it has to be saved as it is @VLAZ

Comment: If you need arbitrary precision decimal numbers in JavaScript, you need to use an existing library or roll your own `BigDecimal` implementation. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742578/bigdecimal-in-javascript).

Comment: try `BigInt(your string here)`

Comment: The user can type a number but *unless you do maths on it*, there is little need to save it as number. If you're only displaying it, then there is literally no difference between number and string. You can *validate* if it's a number but there is little need to *convert it*.

Comment: @I-vasilich-I `9999999999999.99999` is not an integer.

Comment: @I-vasilich-I the number in the question is not an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Well there is a bit limit to what numbers Javascript can handle (until we get `BigInt64` or if you use a library like `decimal.js`). So since it cannot handle more decimals it just truncates at a point. If you would make a bigger number you would see less decimals. If this then leads to the number being "exacly" 9999999999999.99 in your case javascript will correctly show it as 9999999999999.99 and not 9999999999999.99999 since we only have Number and not float, decimal, int, etc.

```
parseFloat(9999999999999.99999);
// 9999999999999.99
parseFloat(9999999999999.9999);
// 9999999999999.99
parseFloat(9999999999999.999);
// 9999999999999.998
parseFloat(9999999999999.99);
// 9999999999999.99
```

Edit: actually it seem to round and not drop.

I hope that explains things.

Comment: Yes but is there any possibility that i can preserve the number exactly the same, like 

ParseFloat("9999999999999.99999") = 9999999999999.99999 or any react js library

Comment: @007DevilsWorkshop yes you can use libraries like `decimal.js` or `BigInt64`

Comment: if you want to use BigInt64 you should look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742578/bigdecimal-in-javascript).

Comment: A BigDecimal can coerce to a number (via implicit call to toString), but that will obviously lead to loss of precision. @n-ata

Comment: @007DevilsWorkshop So try some libraries

Comment: Can you suggest any library? @n-ata

Comment: @007DevilsWorkshop here is [library](https://mikemcl.github.io/decimal.js/)

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at [`decimal.js`](https://github.com/MikeMcl/decimal.js/), this allows an arbitrary level of precision to be specified.

```js
const x = new Decimal("9999999999999.99999");
console.log('x:', x.toString())

// Manipulate x
console.log('x * 2:', x.mul(2).toString())
console.log('x / 2:', x.div(2).toString())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/decimal.js/9.0.0/decimal.min.js" integrity="sha512-zPQm8HS4Phjo9pUbbk+HPH3rSWu5H03NFvBpPf6D9EU2xasj0ZxhYAc/lvv/HVDWMSE1Autj19i6nZOfiVQbFQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: the output will be string is it ? @Terry

Comment: The .toString() call will output the decimal value as a string, however internally it is represented with digits array, exponent and sign. So any mathematical operations performed on it will give an accurate result.

Comment: You can use .toNumber() to convert to a JavaScript number, but risk losing precision.

Comment: Yeah but here I need to keep it as number without losing precision, I cant pass it as string as the logic expects number  @Terry

Comment: The problem being you can't represent 9999999999999.99999 as a Number in JavaScript, it's a limitation of the fact they are stored as 64-bit doubles. So as soon as we convert to a Number precision will be lost. If the logic accepted a Decimal value then this could be made to work.